# Preparing a linear combination of two $1$-occupied states

Tags: quantum-state, circuit-construction

I apologize for a simple question, should be quite trivial. How do I construct a circuit for preparing such a state?
$$
|0\rangle^n \mapsto \cos(\theta)|0...0\underset{i}{1}0...0\rangle + \sin(\theta) |0...0\underset{j}{1}0...0\rangle \ ,
$$
where the $i$th and $j$th qubits are in the $|1\rangle$ state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of such circuit for five qubits.

[image: Circuit]

A gate $Ry$ acting on qubit $q_1$ prepares superposition

$$
\cos(\theta/2)|0\rangle + \sin(\theta/2)|1\rangle.
$$

When qubit $q_1$ is in state $|0\rangle$ (with probability $\cos^2(\theta/2)$), qubit $q_3$ is in state $|1\rangle$ thanks to gate $X$.

When qubit $q_1$ is in state $|1\rangle$ (with probability $\sin^2(\theta/2)$), qubit $q_3$ is in state $|0\rangle$ thanks to gate $X$ and CNOT gate (two negation is equal to no negation).

Other qubits are not changed and remain in state $|0\rangle$. As a result, the circuit produce state
$$
\cos(\theta/2)|00010\rangle + \sin(\theta/2)|01000\rangle.
$$

You can construct similar circuit for any positions $i$ and $j$ simply by putting $Ry$ gate with proper parameter $\theta$ on one qubit, gate $X$ on second qubit and then "connect" them with CNOT gate.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed!